# How buildheap work

Tags: algorithm, heap, heapsort

If I have this A = [4 2 8 6 5 3] and I call BuildHeap(A)

```
BuildHeap(A){
 heap_length[A] ← length[A]
 for i ← floor(length[A]/2) downto 1 do
 Heapify(A, i)
}
```

It will build it like this

```
     4
  2     8
 6 5   3
```

Or like that:

```
     8
  6     4
 2 5   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a min-heap,

```
    2
  4   3
 6 5 8
```

If you create a max-heap,

```
    8
  6   4
 2 5 3
```

Remember, min-heaps will always have the "minimum" element at the top, and max-heaps will always have the "maximum".

The bottom-up process of creating a heap is like this:

[image]

To see an example, go here : http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page502.html